# how by not choosing child value, make all parent value disappear from the result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, notin

My data looks like this: same `PolicyNumber` can have different `ClassCode`. So how to eliminate all rows that contain `PolicyNumber` `PACA1000101-00` if at least one `ClassCode` choosen to be `NOT IN`

So if I say `WHERE ClassCode <> 01183` I want all those records not showing up in a result set.

[image]

Comment: The double negative is troubling.  So you want all records where classcode is 01183? (Sample data w/ expected results!)

Comment: If `PolicyNumber` has ClassCode `01183` I want the`PolicyNumber` and any other `ClassCodes` (which are `69183` and `01183`) that this `PolicyNumber` can have to be gone

Comment: So put another way, if a policyNumber has a single occurrence of a class code 01183, then, you want to exclude that policyNumber from the results.  this seems like a good time to use not in or not exists.  (not exists being faster on larger data sets)

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a not exists and a correlated subquery?

```
Select * 
from table T1
where not exists (Select 1 
                  from table T2 
                  where T1.PolicyNumber = T2.PolicyNumber
                    and classCode = 01183)
```

Another way to do this if you had to join to a 2nd table with different values and you needed values from that table....

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.*
FROM  table T1
LEFT JOIN (Select * 
           from table T2 
           classCode = 01183)
  on T1.PolicyNumber = T2.PolicyNumber
WHERE T2.PolicyNumber is null
```

This says join the table to itself, but only include records on the right side which have a class code of 01183.  Then the where clause says exclude all policy numbers which have at least 1 occurrence of class code 01183.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested but it displayed me `PolicyNumber` with 01183 `ClassCode` only

Comment: change the `<>` to = as above.

Comment: Oh Oh I am sorry.  Yours is correct I just missed`=`

Comment: No, you suggestion is right. If i put `<>` then its not right. 
But `=` eliminates the whole` PolicyNumber'

Comment: Ok, so the above is having the desired effect.  Which was to exclude from the results any policy number having one or more occurrences of a classcode 01183.